# При переходе с native PHP ломается подключение к БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

На хостинге стоит `PHP native(5.6)`, весь сайт работает отлично. При переходе на `PHP 5.5` или `PHP 7.0` пропадает подключение к БД (использую `mysqli`), в `error_log` никаких ошибок нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$mySQL = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'login', 'password', 'table');
if ($stmt = $mySQL->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `razd` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;")){
   while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
      echo $row['article'];
   }
}
mysqli_close($mySQL);
```

**UPD:** Теперь появилась ошибка:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect():
>   (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (2)

Проблема в том, что в `phpMyAdmin` сервер написан как `localhost:3306`, и какие бы вариации `mysqli_connect` я ни пробовал, ни одна не заработала. И порт указывал 5 параметром, и все вариации `localhost` попробовал.

Comment: Вообще номер порта - это 5 параметр. То есть скорее интересно как сейчас работает.

Comment: Чтобы в логах были ошибки, их нужно туда писать `if (!$mySQL) die(mysqli_connect_error());`

Comment: Проблема решилась использованием не `localhost`, а напрямую IP `127.0.0.1`